# Is it expected for sizeof(char) to return 1 instead of 4 when integer promotion takes place in C?

Tags: c, integer, integer-promotion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned char c = 'a';
    c = c + 3;
    printf("%c ", c);
    printf("%zu",sizeof(c));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:d 1

when integer promotion takes place implicitly in c. then why the size of char is printing 1(in bytes) rather 4(in bytes), since the size should increase to 32bits right?

Iam thinking that the output shall be: d 4

Comment: The size of a `char` is, by definition, 1. (A character literal, however like is actually an `int`, so `sizeof('x')` is likely to be larger)

Comment: `sizeof()` is evaluated for type of variable at compile time. It is 1 regardless of how variable is used in other places of program. Your second `printf` is equivaltent to `printf("%zu", (size_t)1)`. Why do you expect it to print 4?

Comment: The argument to `sizeof` does not undergo integer promotions.  When the name of an array is passed to `sizeof`, the array does not decay into a pointer to the first element of the array.  See the definition of [`sizeof`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4) in the C standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct that the calculation of `c + 3` involves integer promotion, i.e. the type of the result is `int`. However, when you store that result in your `char`variable using `c = ...` it will be converted back to a `char` again. The assignment will not (can not) change the size of your variable.

Try this code:

```
char c = 'a';
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(c));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(c + 3));
c = c + 3;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(c));
```

On my system it gives:

```
1
4
1
```

Comment: Thank you! for the answer, I got my doubt clarified

Answer (score -1):

Please see the C99 Standard or [C11 Standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4), under section 6.5.3.4 titled '**The sizeof and _Alignof operators**' - Point #4

> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
> char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1

For the C99 standard, under section 6.5.3.4 titled **The sizeof operator** Point #3 -

> When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or
> signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

Meaning, no matter what implementation of compiler used or environment, the size of `char`, the result will always be 1.

There is a quoted sample of code under Section 5.1.2.3 of the C99 standard, reference #10

> EXAMPLE 2
> In executing the fragment

```
char c1, c2; 
/* ... */ 
c1 = c1 + c2;
```

> the ‘‘integer promotions’’ require that the abstract machine
> promote the value of each variable to int size and then add the two
> ints and truncate the sum. Provided the addition of two chars can be
> done without overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce
> the correct result, the actual execution need only produce the same
> result, possibly omitting the promotions.

So, on the basis of the question, yes, the integer promotion will happen, it is after re-evaluating back to type of `char` will always return back 1 afterwards. As long as there's no over-flow of the value and that it falls under the maximum size of byte value, i.e. 255.

Comment: Wasn't me, but you have `unsigned` in the last sentence, which would be an `int` unless you add `char` to it. i.e. `unsigned foo; printf("%zu\n", sizeof foo);` => `4`.

Comment: Thanks @pmacfarlane was only quoting verbatim what was in the standard, good point though.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the big problem for me with this answer is that it doesn't really answer the question.  The question was not, "What is `sizeof(char)`?" or "Why is `sizeof(char)` always 1?".  No, the question was "Why did `c = c + 3;` not increase the size of `c` from `sizeof(char)` to `sizeof(int)`?"

Comment: Thanks @SteveSummit the part of the question `then why the size of char is printing 1(in bytes)` is what showed the lack of understanding on the OP's part